# How do I scroll to the last id with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want when I click load more button content will automatic scroll to the last id. Hmmm

Example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loadmorebutton").click(function (){
        $('#loadmorebutton').html('');
    $.ajax({
        url: "loadmore.php?lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id"),
        success: function(html){
            if(html){
                $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                $('#loadmorebutton').html('Load More');
            }else{
                $('#loadmorebutton').replaceWith('No more posts to show.');
            }
        }
    });
   });
});
```

[Live Demo](http://demos.hycus.com/load-more/). On the demo I want, after click load more window will scroll to `Post no 51` by example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Button click, find out the window height `var wh = $(window).height();`  and apply it to window scrollTop `$(window).scrollTop(wh)` This will make whatever is on button of the page be first thing on top.

Answer (score 1):

[`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) might be the function you might be requiring.

`var height = 100;`

`$("#postswrapper").scrollTop(height)`